# How can I use multiple IDs in a jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I am puzzled to why this does not work:

```
jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
  jQuery("#first-id","#second-id","#third-id").toggle();
});
```

I want the btn to toggle all of the IDs, but it only reacts on the first one. Any ideas?

Best regards,
Skt

Comment: `jQuery("#first-id, #second-id, #third-id")`

Comment: [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: gah. I can't believe I missed that one! Anyway, thanks so much for the fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass multiple parameters with selectors to jQuery.

Pass a single [parameter where you separate the id's using a comma (`,`)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```js
jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
  jQuery("#first-id, #second-id, #third-id").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn'>Press me</button>

<em id='first-id'>1</em>
<em id='second-id'>2</em>
<em id='third-id'>3</em>
```